# How to pass TextView data to view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

What I want to do is display the picture you clicked on in the collection view before with a custom text view for each one Here is what I have:

Collection View:

```
import UIKit

class ExploreViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var imageGallery = ["29.png","2.png","3.png","9.png","10.png","11.png","12.png","13.png","14.png","15.png","16.png","17.png","1.png","19.png","21.png","22.png","23.png","25.png","26.png","18.png","30.png","4.png"]
    
    var textArr =
    ["Example 1","Example 2","..."]
    
    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    let manager = ExploreDataManager()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //initialize()
        //ExploreViewController.initialize()
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
        AppUtility.lockOrientation(.portrait)
        // Or to rotate and lock
        // AppUtility.lockOrientation(.portrait, andRotateTo: .portrait)
        
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        
        // Don't forget to reset when view is being removed
        AppUtility.lockOrientation(.all)
    }

}

extension ExploreViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imageGallery.count
        //return textDescription.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "exploreCell", for: indexPath) as! ExploreCell
        cell.exploreImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageGallery[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let ExploreViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GalleryViewController") as! GalleryViewController
        
//ExploreViewController.imageDetail = imageGallery[indexPath.row] commented out because of an error
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ExploreViewController, animated: true)
        ExploreViewController.imageReceived = UIImage(named: imageGallery[indexPath.row])!
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ExploreViewController, animated: true)
        
    }
    
}
```

New View Controller that I want the picture and text view to be in:

```
import UIKit

class GalleryViewController: UIViewController{
    
    var imageReceived = UIImage()
    
    var textDescription = ""
    
    @IBOutlet var selectedImage: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet var imageDetail: UITextView!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        selectedImage.image = imageReceived
        imageDetail.text = textDescription
    }
    
}
```

[image: StoryBoard]

Tried this:

```
//ExploreViewController.imageDetail = imageGallery[indexPath.row]
```

Commented out because of an error
*CANNOT BE LABEL*. I will be putting in sentences in textArr and is why I am trying to do txtview.

Comment: In your collection view `didSelectItemAt`, why are you naming a variable as `ExploreViewController`? Don't name a variable the same as a class. Name it something useful like `gallery`. And why push the view controller twice? Once is enough.

Answer (score -1):

To make changes to the text of a `UITextView`, you have to access the `text` property.

So instead of

```
ExploreViewController.imageDetail = imageGallery[indexPath.row]
```

use

```
ExploreViewController.imageDetail.text = imageGallery[indexPath.row]
```

It also looks like you want to display the `ExploreViewController` after a specific item is clicked. You should do this by performing a segue and passing the image and its text instead of instantiating a new `ExploreViewController`.